# How to find the list of available users in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I have a SQL Server 2008 table called "users" which stores users details. I have an aspx page that users will be redirected after they logged in. How might I find the list of users who are currently logged in without any updating this table? Do I need need a separate table to maintain login history? Please provide sample code.

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you looking for a solution that would work in a multi-server load balanced environment, or are you only using a single machine? Does it need to be robust in the event of a server or IIS restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you to use ASp.net Membership and roles functionality. [Membership and Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx)

1. you can store your credential in a session Variable and you can check it .
2. Use SqlState server to maintain session and login  history [SessionState Modes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)
3. You can store credentials in Cookies. which will sent to clients computer

   ```
    if(Session["islogged"] !=null && Session["islogged"] =="1")
   {
     //LoginSuccess
   }
   else
   {
     // loginFailed
   }
   ```

i prefer to use asp.net membership and roles provider to login functionaity, as it is easy and robust.